# Request was not matched by Wiremock stub which was generated by Spring Cloud Contract

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

I am currently trying to build a contract testing test suite using Spring Cloud Contract. I need to test the integration between two services which communicate via gRPC and Protocol Buffers. Therefore, I am using the gRPC feature provided by Spring Cloud Contract (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/project-features.html#features-grpc)). I followed along the code provided in the [example repository](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/main/) (see *producer_grpc* and *consumer_grpc*). The producer side should work fine since the stub is generated and can be used via the *stub-runner*. However, if I try to implement a test on the consumer side which should send a request to the stub, the stub throws a Wiremock error:

```
2022-08-23 08:40:23.211 ERROR [WireMock] 
                                               Request was not matched
                                               =======================

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Closest stub                                             | Request                        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           |
POST                                                       | POST
/service/method                                            | /service/method
                                                           |
Content-Type [matches] : application/grpc.*                | Content-Type: application/grpc
te: trailers                                               | te: trailers
                                                           |
AAAAGz0AAAAbOAAAABszEqYhWwogIHsKICAgICJAdHlwZSI6ICJRRUZpb  | [B@1a1a8bcc                                         
HRlclBpcGUiLAogICAgImZpbHRlckV4cHIiOiB7CiAgICAgICJAdHlwZS  | <<<<< Body does not match
I6ICJFeHByRnVuY3Rpb24iLAogICAgICAiZnVuY3Rpb24iOiB7CiAgICA  |
...more base64 code...                                     |
```

Note: I use the exact same protobuf message for this request as the one which was defined in the contract. Therefore, it should also return the response defined in the contract. Unfortunately, it is hard figure out what the difference between these two payloads is, since the left side is represented in base64 format while on the right side I just get the default toString method from a byte array.

The code on the consumer side looks like that (most parts were taken from [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/main/consumer_grpc/src/test/java/com/example/GrpcTests.java)):

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE, 
classes = ConsumerTest.TestConfiguration.class,
    properties = {
        "grpc.client.myGrpcService.address=static://localhost:5433",
        "grpc.client.myGrpcService.negotiationType=TLS"
    })
public class ConsumerTest {

  @GrpcClient(value = "myGrpcService", interceptorNames = "fixedStatusSendingClientInterceptor")
  MyGrpcServiceGrpc.MyGrpcServiceBlockingStub blockingStub;

  int port;

  @RegisterExtension
  static StubRunnerExtension rule = new StubRunnerExtension()
      .downloadStub("mygroupid", "myartifactid", "0.0.0", "stubs")
      .stubsMode(StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL)
      .withHttpServerStubConfigurer(MyWireMockConfigurer.class);

  @BeforeEach
  public void setupPort() {
    this.port = rule.findStubUrl("mygroupid", "myartifactid").getPort();
  }

  @Test
  void initialTest() {
    MyProtoMessage request = MyProtoMessage.newBuilder()
        [...]
        .build();

    Iterator<MyResponse> iterator = blockingStub.myMethod(request);
    // no element found, since the request does not match
    MyResponse current = iterator.next();
  }

  static class MyWireMockConfigurer extends WireMockHttpServerStubConfigurer {
    @Override
    public WireMockConfiguration configure(WireMockConfiguration httpStubConfiguration,
        HttpServerStubConfiguration httpServerStubConfiguration) {
      return httpStubConfiguration.dynamicHttpsPort()
          .httpsPort(5433);
    }
  }


  @Configuration
  @ImportAutoConfiguration(GrpcClientAutoConfiguration.class)
  static class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public GrpcChannelConfigurer keepAliveClientConfigurer() {
      return (channelBuilder, name) -> {
        if (channelBuilder instanceof NettyChannelBuilder) {
          try {
            ((NettyChannelBuilder) channelBuilder)
                .useTransportSecurity()
                .negotiationType(NegotiationType.TLS)
                .sslContext(GrpcSslContexts.forClient()
                    .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
                    .build());
          } catch (SSLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
          }
        }
      };
    }

    @Bean
    ClientInterceptor fixedStatusSendingClientInterceptor() {
      return new ClientInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method,
            CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {
          ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> call = next.newCall(method, callOptions);
          return new ClientCall<ReqT, RespT>() {
            @Override
            public void start(Listener<RespT> responseListener, Metadata headers) {
              Listener<RespT> listener = new Listener<RespT>() {
                @Override
                public void onHeaders(Metadata headers) {
                  responseListener.onHeaders(headers);
                }

                @Override
                public void onMessage(RespT message) {
                  responseListener.onMessage(message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onClose(Status status, Metadata trailers) {
                  responseListener.onClose(Status.OK, trailers);
                }

                @Override
                public void onReady() {
                  responseListener.onReady();
                }
              };
              call.start(listener, headers);
            }

            @Override
            public void request(int numMessages) {
              call.request(numMessages);
            }

            @Override
            public void cancel(@Nullable String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
              call.cancel(message, cause);
            }

            @Override
            public void halfClose() {
              call.halfClose();
            }

            @Override
            public void sendMessage(ReqT message) {
              call.sendMessage(message);
            }
          };
        }
      };
    }
  }
}
```

The contract looks like this:

```
package contracts

import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.http.ContractVerifierHttpMetaData

Contract.make {
  description("Contract Test")
  request {
    method 'POST'
    url '/service/method'
    body(fileAsBytes("request.bin"))
    headers {
      contentType("application/grpc")
      header("te", "trailers")
    }
  }
  response {
    status 200
    body(value(producer($(anyNonEmptyString())), consumer(fileAsBytes("response.bin"))))
    headers {
      contentType("application/grpc")
      header("grpc-encoding", "identity")
      header("grpc-accept-encoding", "gzip")
    }
  }
  metadata([
    "verifierHttp": [
      "protocol": ContractVerifierHttpMetaData.Protocol.H2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE.toString()
    ]
  ])
}
```

So the question would be: What do I need to do in order to match the request of the stub (which is defined in the contract)? Am I missing something when using the stub?

Comment: Can you update the question with an example of a contract?

Comment: I've updated the post by providing the contract. Strangely, this error does not appear anymore after I restarted my machine. However, I now get an error from gRPC saying that it "Received unexpected EOS on empty DATA frame from server". This might be caused by the fact that the method from the gRPC service returns a stream (therefore, the response is an iterator of the response protobuf message). Is there a way to define such stream-responses in a contract? @MarcinGrzejszczak

Comment: Nope, AFAIR we don't support streaming

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Do you think that there is a workaround for that? Because I would want to retrieve multiple responses from the generated stub when sending a request. @MarcinGrzejszczak

Comment: Im getting "Received unexpected EOS on empty DATA frame from server " exception after wiremock returns the response. Felix could you find a solution for this problem ?